# Excel VBA import xml file

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I've used google but i can't seem to find a simple answer to the following question:

How do I import a XML file into an Excel worksheet using VBA. So for example, i have a file named test.xml in the folder c:\test. I want excel to copy the data of test.xml to the second sheet using VBA

Comment: This question has been asked before: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423644/load-xml-into-excel-through-vba

Answer (score 1):

On the Data tab >> Get External Data >> From other sources >> From XML data import

Recording a macro while doing this gave me:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= "C:\Stuff\test.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
                         Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")
```

Start with that and see if it works for your file.  If you run into problems you'll need to post a sample of the actual XML.

Comment: Ok, this comes as a real supprise. I also used the macro tool, but afterword the code didn't work......Thnx for the feedback.