# XML to XLSX command, script or code

Tags: c#, xml, excel, powershell, batch-file

I have a process that generates some large XML files which I then import into Excel manually. I would like to automate this Excel sheet conversion using some type of command batch or script language like powershell but not sure if this is possible.

The manual steps in Excel are:

```
Data --> FormXML Data Import --> Browse for XML file --> Excel creates schema using existing XML table in workshee ($A$1) .
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a macro that once executed imports the XML into Excel then execute the macro via VBscript:
[Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line)

See here how to add a macro to import XML to Excel from VBA:
[Excel VBA import xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666220/excel-vba-import-xml-file)