# How can I load a domDocument into Excel as an xml table?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have read the post ([Load XML into Excel through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423644/load-xml-into-excel-through-vba/16423709#16423709)) regarding loading an xml file into excel using `LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList` and the reference there to use a local file for testing. This works perfectly for testing but the xml I need to use is received from an http Post request. How can I use a `domDocument` to create a table in the worksheet?

What I need is something like:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=domDocument, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
```

Writing the data into the workbook is possible but I'm no great expert at working with Nodes, `xlXmlLoadImportToList` seems to provide the perfect solution.

Comment: An MSXML DOM document has a `save` method to save to a file so if you want to load from a file the call `domDocument.save("file.xml")` and then load from that file with your preferred way.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that is an option but I'd rather not have to save the file as xml unless there is no way to get it directly into the worksheet as an xml table (or any other format for that matter).

Comment: But... it certainly works so that'll be the answer. TY.